# C# - How to copy a file being written

Tags: c#

I have a class implementing a Log file writer.
Logs must be written for the application to "work correctly", so it is of the utmost importance that the writings to disk are ok.

The log file is kept open for the whole life of the application, and write operations are accordingly very fast:

```
var logFile = new FileInfo(filepath);
_outputStream = logFile.Open(FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
```

Now, I need to synchronize this file to a network path, during application lifetime.
This network copy can be slightly delayed without problems. The important bit is that I have to guarantee that it doesn't interfere with log writing.

Given this network copy must be eventually consistent, I need to make sure that all file contents are written, instead only the last message(s).

A previous implementation used heavy locking and a simple `System.IO.File.Copy(filepath, networkPath, true)`, but I would like to lock as little as possible.

How could I approach this problem? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You could when logging, also write to another file if I understand correctly.

Comment: I don't have any guarantee that previous messages where written remotely correctly. So I would like to make sure I'm performing a full file copy, instead of writing only the one message I'm writing at a time.

Comment: _" so it is of the utmost importance that the writings to disk are ok."_ You _cannot_ guarantee that 100% with pure .Net. On newer system maybe not even with Win API. You probably need to log to a DB that guarantees [ACID](https://database.guide/what-is-acid-in-databases/).

Comment: @Fildor would you care to elaborate? I know that there are write buffers managed at the OS level, and the kind of guarantee provided by the OS when the buffers are flushed is ok for our use (which is not, technically, 100%, I understand). Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could put the log file in a specific folder and make it available as a network folder, or write in your local log file and in a network log file. Streaming a file while it is being written into is asking for bugs and will have a huge performance penalty in your app, hence the heavy use of locking.

Comment: OK, I assumed that is was not enough since you stressed that point. So, if we can assume flushing sufficient, then how is your stance towards file rolling?

Comment: I am asking because you could write to local file 1 up to let's say size X (or for n Minutes, whatever may be your threshold). Then switch to writing to local file 2 and upload local file 1. Then if local file 2 hits the threshold, write to lf3 and upload lf2 ... That way you wouldn't even be bothered by a temporary network outage.

Comment: Codingwiz that is kinda what I was suspecting... @Fildor thanksfor your suggestion. The file is rolled at a fixed rate of one per week, which I cannot change. But it should be copied more frequently than that. The previous implementation locked the file twice for each single message written. Now I lock when writing only for serialization purposes, but  I need to manage the backup file. I'm starting to think about copying it offline every couple of seconds, in a separate thread...

Comment: And if you make the "file" actually be a single-file database, you could make use of structured logging, have transactions for free and better physical-write guarantees and _maybe_ even faster.

Comment: @Fildor yes, I know, but I'm stuck with a legacy message format I cannot change for legal reasons (it would affect regulated processes).

Comment: You could use a MemoryMappedFile to load the contents to a in-memory buffer and upload them during reading. Take a "snapshot" of the source files current size and let the MemoryMappedFile read exactly that many bytes. Write those bytes to a file and upload. 
I just want to point out that as long as there is a network involved you will never be able to guarantee successful write / copy operations as networks like to not work when you need them.

Comment: Ah, ok. So this is some kind of Compliance Audit Log. So, I don't know what your exact requirements are, but: having worked with MS SQL Server I know you could: Write your lines to a DB Table. Server would reside on the same machine, so you are technically keeping the exact formatted lines in a local file. But then you can also: **automate to Export the Table to .txt file** locally, export to remote, backup the db (local, remote) mirror the table to a remote DB ... and this is probably possible with other dbms, too - I just happen to know it of MS SQL Server. Maybe that's an option for you.